# How to get JSON from getRequest

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have a string in the form:

```
{"Fruit":"Meat",
     "Vegetable":[
       {"Name":"Author1","Date":"12"},
       {"Name":"Author2","Date":"2"},
       {"Name":"Author3","Date":"14"}
       .
       .
       .
       {"Name": "AuthorN", "Date":"18"}
    ]
}
```

that's associated with a JSON/GetNames service.

What's a JavaScript function that can parse and return every "Name" under "Vegetable"?

Comment: `JSON.parse` and iteration will do that.

Comment: What do you mean by *getting JSON* from that? It *is* JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this:

```
var jsonStr = '{"Fruit":"Meat","Vegetable":[{"Name":"Author1","Date":"12"},{"Name":"Author2","Date":"2"},{"Name":"Author3","Date":"14"}...{"Name": "AuthorN", "Date":"18"}]}';    
var object = JSON.parse(jsonStr),
    names = [];

for (var i = 0; i < object.Vegetable.length; i++) {
    var item = object.Vegetable[i],
        name = item.Name;
    names.push(name);
}
//Finally print the result:
console.log(names);
```

Or If you just want o print the names (shorter):

```
var object = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
for (var i = 0; i < object.Vegetable.length; i++)
    console.log(object.Vegetable[i].Name);
```

Cheers

Comment: If I wanted to print the names so that they can become members of a drop-down menu, how can I do that by using a GET method on the other part of my script?

Comment: The alternative to using a function is by <select><option>...</option></select> but it's not practical in a scenario with a large number of members.

Answer (score 1):

Ehh a `for` loop generally works (once the data has been parsed).

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.vegetable.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.vegetable[i].name);
}
```

Comment: for (var i=0, l=data.vegetable.length; i<l ; i++)